# Form submission not calling on Javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a JS file I am trying to have executed and return results on button submit (kirk.js). In my form I have the action send the on submit to Google.com, however, in my  it should be overridden based on preventDefault. However, on form submit, it is still sending me to Google, and not bringing in the functionality of kirk.js.

Here is the script tag itself

```
<script> src="src/kirk.js" document.getElementById('searchbar').addEventListener('submit', function (e) { e.preventDefault(); });</script>
```

Here is the button + script together

```
<form target="_blank" action="https://google.com" id=searchbar >
                      <div class="inner-form">
                        <div class="input-field first-wrap">
                          <div class="svg-wrapper">
                            <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24">
                              <path d="M15.5 14h-.79l-.28-.27C15.41 12.59 16 11.11 16 9.5 16 5.91 13.09 3 9.5 3S3 5.91 3 9.5 5.91 16 9.5 16c1.61 0 3.09-.59 4.23-1.57l.27.28v.79l5 4.99L20.49 19l-4.99-5zm-6 0C7.01 14 5 11.99 5 9.5S7.01 5 9.5 5 14 7.01 14 9.5 11.99 14 9.5 14z"></path>
                            </svg>
                          </div>
                          <input id="search" type="text" placeholder="Paste a domain here" />
                        </div>
                        <div class="input-field second-wrap">
                          <button class="btn-search" action="https://www.google.com" type="submit">SEARCH</button>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                      <span class="info">ex. JeepBeef.com</span>
                    </form>
                    <script> src="src/Kirk.js" document.getElementById('searchbar').addEventListener('submit', function (e) { e.preventDefault(); });</script>
```

Any help as to what I am doing wrong is appreciated

Comment: `Here is the script tag itself` looks like a syntax error - do you see a syntax error (or ANY error) in the browser developer tools console?

Comment: @Bravo I do not. Any reccomendations?

Comment: my reccomendations is to have a look on your debugger (F12)

Comment: `src="src/Kirk.js"` give this error  --> `Uncaught SyntaxError: unexpected token: identifier`

Comment: if that script tag is, in reality `<script src="src/kirk.js"> document.getElementById etc</script>` then the code won't run, since you'll be loading script from the file `src/kirk.js` - you can't have inline and external js in the same tag

Answer (score 0):

There is an issue in your script. You specify both js file import and the js function call in a HTML Script tag. This doesn't work like that.

If you want to import a JS File, you need to use a separate script tag for that and for the JS Function, you need a separate tag.

So, your code should be something similar to the below one:

```html
<form target="_blank" action="https://google.com" id=searchbar >
                      <div class="inner-form">
                        <div class="input-field first-wrap">
                          <div class="svg-wrapper">
                            <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24">
                              <path d="M15.5 14h-.79l-.28-.27C15.41 12.59 16 11.11 16 9.5 16 5.91 13.09 3 9.5 3S3 5.91 3 9.5 5.91 16 9.5 16c1.61 0 3.09-.59 4.23-1.57l.27.28v.79l5 4.99L20.49 19l-4.99-5zm-6 0C7.01 14 5 11.99 5 9.5S7.01 5 9.5 5 14 7.01 14 9.5 11.99 14 9.5 14z"></path>
                            </svg>
                          </div>
                          <input id="search" type="text" placeholder="Paste a domain here" />
                        </div>
                        <div class="input-field second-wrap">
                          <button class="btn-search" action="https://www.google.com" type="submit">SEARCH</button>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                      <span class="info">ex. JeepBeef.com</span>
                    </form>
                    <script> src="src/Kirk.js" </script>
                    <script type="text/javascript">
                       document.getElementById('searchbar').addEventListener('submit', function (e) { e.preventDefault(); });
                    </script>
```

Comment: Tried that, but nothing seems to happen on the form submit

Comment: Do you get any errors in your chrome console?

Comment: @HarshanaSerasinghe - you're assuming OP is using *Chrome* of course ... it's better to ask if they have an error in the **browser** console - since everyone has a browser, and only 60% of people use google malware to browse the internet